Connecting two plugins with php code on wordpress
Please someone write a code that you can add listing from hivepress plugin only if you have a membership in paid member subscriptions plugin.Else, do not allow access to the users in this page.
I tried to use chatgpt because I do not know php but it didn't work.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

We are not a write-my-code service, sorry. And even if we were, this specification is far too short and vague. We can help you with a specific programming problem within your attempt to implement what you need.  If you don't know php, you should either try to learn it, or hire a programmer to work for you. Stackoverflow isn't a free replacement for your effort, or for professional services. It's a place where programmers help other programmers with their clear coding issues.
